# VBA code to use Excel sheets as a small database

Tags: database, excel, vba

Can anyone recommend a class or library of VBA code written for Excel to use tabs as small database tables?  If not, would anyone be interested in criticizing the code that I have been using, in an attempt to improve it (I'm sure it's full of holes).

I realize that using Excel as a database may not be the best solution and I hope to one day have a proper server setup for this project but for the time being that is not an option.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you should give this a read, then rework your question. Can't imagine anyone is going to be able to help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use the ADO (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library) to query Excel as if it were a database.  If you have a specific question on how to improve your code, post it here.  If you are interested suggestions on how you should refactor existing code, you should post your code on Code Review.

Comment: What speaks against for example SQLite? No install required and for all platforms. Choosing excel as a *DataBase* makes me cringe inside me ;)

Comment: Even using Microsoft Access seems like a better option then Excel. If you need some functions of Excel then perhaps this website will be of help. It covers a lot of the basics of ADO, and using an Excel front end, Access back end. http://www.datawright.com.au/excel_resources/excel_access_and_ado.htm

Comment: Thank you Thomas, that was exactly what I was looking for, I'm glad you could put that together from my question!

Others - I agree, Excel isn't the best solution but my hands are tied here.  It is definitely cringe-worthy but it was worse w/o ADODB.